# best approach to debug "corrupted double-linked list" crash

Tags: linux, c++11, gdb, heap-memory

I am in the process of debugging a "corrupted double-linked list" crash. I have seen the source and understand the chunk struct and the fd/bk pointers, etc, so I think I know why this crash has occurred. I am now trying to fix it and I have a couple of questions.

Question #1: where (with respect to the pointer returned from malloc) is the malloc_chunks struct maintained?  Are they before the memory block or after it?

Question #2: the malloc_chunks for allocated memory are different from the malloc_chunks for unallocated memory. It appears (??) that the allocated buffer case does not have the fd/bk pointers.  Is this correct?

Question #3: what is the recommended approach to debug this type of error?  I am assuming that I should put a break point for the malloc_chunks so I can break on when the struct is overwritten. But I am not sure how to access those malloc structs so I can set a break point in gdb.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
-Andres

Comment: Are you talking about your own linked lists code/implementation? Or are you talking about internal glibc structures related to malloc ? (If so, forget about those -that's just a symptom find the part of your program that causes the issue)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I am talking about the malloc_chunk struct of malloc.c  and I am trying to find where in my code those malloc_chunk structs are getting clobbered which is causing the crash. I do not understand the wisdom in you suggestion to forget about those structs.  That is the only clue I have. I thought I should set a gdb watch for when that struct gets written to so I can find out where in my code I am overwritting some memory.

Comment: `Question #3: what is the recommended approach to debug this type of error?` - Run you program under `valgring` or other utility which can reveal issues in memory allocations and accesses. With 99.9% probability exactly these issues cause such errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the recommended approach to debug this type of error?

The usual way is *not* to peek into GLIBC internals, but to use a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), either of which is likely to point you straight at the problem.

**Update:**

> Valgrind crashes ...

You should try building the latest Valgrind version from source, and if that still crashes, report the crash to Valgrind developers.

Chances are the Valgrind problem is already fixed, and building new Valgrind and testing your program with it will *still* be faster than trying to debug GLIBC internals (heap corruption bugs are *notoriously* difficult to find by program inspection or debugging).

> AddressSanitizer, I thought it was a clang only tool -- I do not think it is available for linux.

Two points:

1. Clang works just fine on Linux, I use it almost every day,
2. [Recent GCC versions](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) have an equivalent `-fsanitize=address` option.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have tried valgrind, but *valgrind* crashes when running my program. My program runs fine outside of valgrind, and runs fine in gdb also--gdb stops (as it should) when I get this memory error--that is how I know it is a memory problem in the malloc.c code. But for some reason valgrind crashes so it is useless to me. As for AddressSanitizer, I thought it was a clang only tool--I do not think it is available for linux.

Comment: thanks for your help. I finally resolved the bug. Your answers were helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to debug heap overruns without valgrind.

One way is to use a malloc debug library such as Electric Fence. It will make your rogram crash exactly at the moment of accessing an illegal address in the heap.

The other way is to use built-in debug capabilities of GNU malloc. See `man mcheck`. If you call `mcheck_pedantic` before the first call to `malloc`, then every memory block is checked at every allocation. This is very slow but does allow you to isolate the fault.